# How do you properly set up a MySQL database to store encrypted information born of the PHP OpenSSL cypher / random pseudo bytes / encrypt functions?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, openssl

I've been toying with this for a minute and I can't seem to get this right. I've altered the collation and the varchar length multiple times, but all I'm getting are blank fields once I submit. Unencrypted, they populate the fields just fine. But the second I encrypt them - it's blank-o town.

I figured it's just using a different character encoding, but either I've totally missed the correct encoding, or it's something else.

This is basically what I'm doing as far as the encryption:

```
$cm = 'aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256';
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cm);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

$accessToken = 'AA44FC23459DD9A9D009DABBAAABF';

// this is just to show what the iv and c_key end up looking like
$iv = ' ... �u0�du ... ';
$c_key = ' ... 8�!Ò��u0�du�2⮩e ... '; // ellipses are just a fill in

// then I go ahead and encrypt...
$SSLaccessToken = openssl_encrypt($pw, $cm, $c_key, $options=0, $iv);
```

But the second I try to stick it in the db, it donks on me.
So - what am I missing? It's gotta be the character set, right? 
That's the only thing that makes sense to me - but how do I nail this down?

Comment: You didn't show any code at all, but did you use base64encode() before you save it?

Comment: The key, IV and ciphertext are all binary data - treat them as such.  It is a common mistake to assume that the result of an encryption operation is a string - it isn't.

Comment: huh, learn something new every day. I did not know that - though, I guess it goes with the assumption. Of course it's binary. *face-palm*
Thanks